# Jeyne Westerling's fate

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

Having watched the latest *Game of Thrones* episode ("[Bear and the Maiden Fair](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Bear_and_the_Maiden_Fair_%28song%29)"), I feel I've had a small epiphany. There's rumor and theory going around that in the books, Robb got Jeyne pregnant. Jeyne didn't attend the RW, and afterward was swept away. In the show, we know that Talisa is a replacement for Jeyne. And we find out that Talisa is pregnant. Looking over the credits, Martin himself wrote this episode (all except the bear scenes). Is it now safe to assume that Jeyne is pregnant?

**EDIT**

So, with last nights episode, how are we to interpret Jeyne's fate? Will GRRM take that into consideration when writing about Jeyne in the future? Or will he just say "eff em", and write that Jeyne was pregnant, had the heir, and he kicked face? Did GRRM have any say in the "Rains of Castamere" episode at all?

Comment: Related: [Why was Jeyne Westerling replaced with Talisa Maegyr?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11677)

Answer (score 14):

This is located in Chapter 44 of A Feast For Crows.

> As you will.” Jaime turned to the daughter. “I am sorry for your loss. The boy had courage, I’ll give him that. There is a question I must ask you. Are you carrying his child, my lady?”
>
> Jeyne burst from her chair and would have fled the room if the guard at the door had not seized her by the arm. “She is not,” said Lady Sybell, as her daughter struggled to escape. “I made certain of that, as your lord father bid me.”

So Jeyne is not pregnant.

Also, further in the chapter.

> Good.” Jaime would as lief have Tully reach Casterly Rock safely, but better dead than fled. “Best keep some archers near Lord Westerling’s daughter as well.”
>
> Ser Forley seemed taken aback. “Gawen’s girl? She’s—”
>
> “—the Young Wolf’s widow,” Jaime finished, “and twice as dangerous as Edmure if she were ever to escape us.”
>
> “As you say, my lord. She will be watched.

So Jaime has watch over her.

Comment: "So Jeyne is not pregnant." is a strong claim. People lie

Comment: especially when "people" means "pregnant girl's mother" :)

Comment: Especially when one's daughter's head is on the chopping block if she should produce an heir.

Comment: I agree, it's a really strong claim. There wouldn't be rumor and theory swirling about it if it were that cut and dry. And again, given that GRRM wrote the episode, I think it lends a slight more credence to the theory.

Comment: When Lady Sybell says "I made certain of that" it means she forced Jeyne to drink moon tea, aborting any fetus. Given Jeyne's reaction it's fairly obvious she was pregnant before the treatment.

Answer (score 3):

I think an answer based on the series can now be given, since Season 3 Episode 9 aired.

Obvious episode 9 spoilers ahead

> Talisa attends to the Red Wedding. She has an obviously round belly. She gets murdered.

Based on this and on the citations of Terry's answer, we can assume that she is not to be taken as a hint for what happens to Jeyne Westerling. Her fate is different. Maybe Jeyne will be murdered because she is still faithful to Robb, but this will be a different story, just another details that changed between the series and the books.