# Was Robb Stark's wife or her mother complicit in the "red wedding"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the book, not the HBO series; Robb's mother (Catelyn) complains to Robb's wife (Jeyne Westerling) that she's not pregnant and Jeyne says that she's trying. Then Lord Tywin Lanister - who has helped plan the Red Wedding - says with all certainty, "Robb's wife will bear him no children."

In the book Jeyne does not attend the Red Wedding and AFAIK she was a Lady from a family who Robb defeats. There was something about her mother being a little sly or secretive.

Did anyone come across any information about what became of Jeyne and what her reaction to the Red Wedding was, or what her mother was up to?

Comment: There are some interesting fan theories about this, but the question really needs an [edit] to, at the very least, actually say his wife's name. It's not like that's hard information to find!

Comment: Good pick-up. In the Jamie chapter where he meets Sybill Spicer at Riverrun, she mentions that she ensured it as well. Also, when Catelyn asks Jeyne, Jeyne replies something like "my mother is brewing me a tea which is supposed to help" <-- that "tea" is thought to have been [Moon Tea](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Moon_tea) A.K.A "Tansy Tea"!

Comment: Also, related, probably dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/35608/21267

Comment: Since there are a lot of discrepancies between books and show like that, it would be safe to assume that GRRM - being involved with show at that level - "improves" on the bloodiness of the story and, as a side effect, discarding some of the plots from the book. It is interesting to see how far he will go. Let's call it a "psychiatric observation of the suspect"  of sorts...